# Git tags with quote names on Windows

Tags: windows, git, github, double-quotes

We've got a repo on GitHub with several tags **with quotes** `"` in the name. Occasionally, some Windows hosts will fail to fetch with the error below. I don't know why some Windows hosts fail to fetch and others don't, if we solved that that would be great.

> fatal: Unable to create 'C:/src/code/tags/some_tag_"with_quotes".lock': Invalid argument

As a workaround, we deleted the tags on GitHub, but inevitably someone who has this tag locally runs a `git push` and pushes the tag back into GitHub. Having everyone reclone will be painful.

These tags cannot be deleted locally (on Windows), the same error is generated.

Comment: Please be precise whether **single** or **double quotes** are used. I suggest sending a detailed email to the [Git mailing list](http://git-scm.com/community).

Comment: Are the issues persistent? That is, if a Windows box doesn't work, will it work at other times, or not?

Comment: Double quotes, @JJD, thanks for the git mailling list tip.

Comment: Good question, @andyg0808, it's persistent for sure, but not sure if it's persistent for that host or the repo on that host, I'll get back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note: This answer has been torn apart and rewritten from its original version**

I wonder if you're having issues with the filesystem's permitted characters in filenames. For example, [according to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations), FAT does not permit double-quotes (`"`). According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations), NTFS will accept double-quotes only if a filename is in the Posix namespacem, but I cannot seem to find that information anywhere else. Further, Microsoft seems to [recommend](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) *avoiding* double-quotes in filenames. Posix appears to only allow `A-Za-z_.-` in "portable" filenames[¹](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_278). See Wikipedia on [filesystem limitations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#Comparison_of_filename_limitations) and [filesystem capabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#Limits) for more.

Perhaps you might try the Cygwin version of Git. It appears that Cygwin manages to support quotes in filenames on Windows.

Comment: The issue is almost certainly an interaction between the file system and git. That said, I'm working on NTFS and I'm not sure how I could create a file with a double quote in the name. Every method I try generates an error of some kind.

Comment: Good idea, I'll give that a whack in ~12 hours

Comment: Good call, @andy0808, cygwin did the trick. I'm going to try a little more to see if I can figure out why some hosts need to create this file on "git fetch", since that's the root of my problem, but if not I'll accept this.

Comment: Also, no need to point out your answer was edited! SO tracks edit history, so I know you updated :P